# CSV file creation issue

Tags: python, excel, file, csv

I'm creating a csv file from a python script with this lines:

```
def createFile():
    logfile = csv.writer(open('logfile.csv', 'wb'), dialect='excel')
    formater = zip(dates, hours, threadids, loglevels, errorcodes, errormessage)
    for i in formater:
        logfile.writerow(i)
```

And everything works fine until I open the file with Excel because it opens the whole text in one column. This is how one row from the csv looks like:

```
4/29/12,22:44:32:865 EDT,0000004b,A,CHFW0019I,The Transport Channel Service has started chain chain_308.
```

Is there any way to open the file splitted in columns how it should be?
Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saved the following in `foo.csv` and it opens fine in Excel.

```
4/29/12,22:44:32:865 EDT,0000004b,A,CHFW0019I,The Transport Channel Service has started chain chain_308.
4/29/12,22:44:32:865 EDT,0000004b,A,CHFW0019I,The Transport Channel Service has started chain chain_308.
4/29/12,22:44:32:865 EDT,0000004b,A,CHFW0019I,The Transport Channel Service has started chain chain_308.
4/29/12,22:44:32:865 EDT,0000004b,A,CHFW0019I,The Transport Channel Service has started chain chain_308.
4/29/12,22:44:32:865 EDT,0000004b,A,CHFW0019I,The Transport Channel Service has started chain chain_308.
```

[image]

You might want to check if you have the right list separator configured in your regional settings using one of the following:

1. Windows Start Button > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Regional Options > Customize > List Separator.
2. Windows Start Button > Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Formats > Additional Settings > List Separator.

Note that you can also launch 'Regional and Language Options' with the command `intl.cpl`, i.e. press Windows + R button and enter `intl.cpl` and press the 'OK' button.

[image]

Comment: I tried creating a file manually and it doesn't work either. Does your excel a custom setup created? I mean if it takes the comma as a separator by default. btw...I'm using Excel 2010, maybe it is different.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office Excel 2003 as well as Microsoft Office Excel 2007. The screenshot is from the former. No, they are not custom setup. Which version of Microsoft Windows are you using?

Comment: @Nucklear I've edited my response to tell you how to find the list separator setting for your system.

Comment: Thanks, I checked your response as solution for future reads.

Answer (score 2):

For Excel to automatically parse your .CSV and split it into columns without you either do so or it asking, your delimiter will need to match your Locale Delimiter which you can find under

`Control Panel -> Region & Language -> Additional Settings -> List Seperator`

And that needs to match the column delimiter you are using in your .CSV file for Excel to open and split the columns correctly.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The problem is that the Spanish lang uses ; as separators.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your CSV should be:

```
sep=,
```

This manner your are saying to Excel to delimit the content by "," automatically.